# User management, authentication and acl plugin for CakePHP?

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, acl

I am pretty new to CakePHP, having been using rails for a little while. My question is, can anyone recommend a good user management, authentication and acl plugin or component for Cake?

I have come across [this one](http://conseil-recherche-innovation.net/authake), but it has not been updated since 2008. If not can anyone recommend a good book/tutorial site for this kind of set up? I am more than happy to sit down and write this kind of thing myself, but would rather use a tested community plug-in.

Cheers

Comment: Great question.  I haven't found a great solution for this stuff in Cake.

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Auth which is both framework-agnostic and database-agnostic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't yet found a plugin that I've been completely satisfied with. I've been using the [SimpleAclComponent](http://svn.mozilla.org/addons/trunk/site/app/controllers/components/simple_acl.php) and [SimpleAuthComponent](http://svn.mozilla.org/addons/trunk/site/app/controllers/components/simple_auth.php) (that are based on 
[A lightweight approach to ACL - The 33 lines of Magic](http://debuggable.com/posts/a-lightweight-approach-to-acl-the-33-lines-of-magic:480f4dd6-639c-44f4-a62a-49a8cbdd56cb)) to build a custom solution.

Answer (score 6):

I found this one which is updated, works with latest CakePHP v1.3.. But haven't tested it though. Link: http://github.com/jedt/spark_plug

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [phpGACL plugin](https://cakeforge.org/projects/phpgacl-cake/) for CakePHP - I've had some amount of success with it but it takes a bit of getting used to.  You're best checking out the 1.2 branch from the Cakeforge repository though, rather than just going for the "download" link on the plugin's home page, which hasn't been updated for some time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am ideally after something that deals with the sign up/email confirmation etc as well as the ACL and authentication. phpGACL looks fantastic though, so if I cannot do this as a single plugin, perhaps I can find three...?

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using this one, http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/acl-management-plugin,
but I had to modify it a bit to get it to manage CRUD.  I'm curious what others will post in this thread.

-Matt

Answer (score 1):

It took some wrestling, but I did eventually get authentication and acl working via built in CakePHP components, Auth and Acl.

Getting it setup was smooth until it came time to grant and deny permissions. For this I use an Acl management plugin by Jeff Loiselle that I got from http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/acl-management-plugin

Answer (score 1):

I use this nice plugin : http://sourceforge.net/projects/pippoacl/
You could manage users, groups and permissions of groups with ajax in very nice and user friendly interface

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all what is posted above but nothing can beat [Authake](https://github.com/nchankov/authake)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one https://github.com/CakeDC/users
It is from CakeDC

Answer (score 0):

[PoundCake Control Panel](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bancer/) works with CakePHP 1.3